# C: incomplete definition of type 'struct date' error

Tags: c

i started learning C and just ran into an issue.

I created a date ADT and would like to test it out :)

basically, i would like to read in a string from standard input, convert it to the date and print it out on standard output.

after compiling these files i got the following errors:

```
datetest.c:15:45: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct date'
  printf("Year: %d Month: %d Day: %d", d->year, d->month, d->day);
                                       ~^
./date.h:4:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct date'
typedef struct date Date;
```

What am i doing wrong?

date.c:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct date {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};

/*
 * date_create creates a Date structure from `datestr`
 * `datestr' is expected to be of the form "dd/mm/yyyy"
 * returns pointer to Date structure if successful,
 *         NULL if not (syntax error)
 */
Date *date_create(char *datestr) {
  Date *d = (Date *)malloc(sizeof(Date));
  const char delimiter[2] = "/";
  char *token;

  if (d != NULL) {  
    token = strtok(datestr, delimiter);
    d->day = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    d->month = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    d->year = atoi(token);
    //printf("Day: %d Month: %d Year: %d\n", d->day, d->month, d->year);    
    //printf("Day: %p Month: %p Year: %p\n", *d->day, *d->month, *d->year);
  }
  return d;
};

/*
 * date_duplicate creates a duplicate of `d'
 * returns pointer to new Date structure if successful,
 *         NULL if not (memory allocation failure)
 */
Date *date_duplicate(Date *d) {
  Date *dd = (Date *)malloc(sizeof(Date));
  if (dd != NULL) {
    dd->day = d->day;
    dd->month = d->month;
    dd->year = d->year;
  }
  return dd;
};

/*
 * date_compare compares two dates, returning <0, 0, >0 if
 * date1<date2, date1==date2, date1>date2, respectively
 */
int date_compare(Date *date1, Date *date2) {
  if (date1->year < date2->year)
    return -1;
  else if (date1->year > date2->year)
    return 1;
  else {
    if (date1->month < date2->month)
      return -1;
    else if (date1->month > date2->month)
      return 1;
    else {
      if (date1->day < date2->day)
    return -1;
      else if (date1->day > date2->day)
    return 1;
      else
    return 0;
    }
  }
};

/*
 * date_destroy returns any storage associated with `d' to the system
 */
void date_destroy(Date *d) {
  if (d != NULL)
    free(d);
};
```

datetest.c:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  Date *d;
  char buf[1024], *s;

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
    if (!(d = date_create(buf))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create a date.\n");
    return -1;
    }
      printf("Year: %d Month: %d Day: %d", d->year, d->month, d->day);
  }
}
```

date.h:

```
#ifndef _DATE_H_INCLUDED_
#define _DATE_H_INCLUDED_

typedef struct date Date;

/*
 * date_create creates a Date structure from `datestr`
 * `datestr' is expected to be of the form "dd/mm/yyyy"
 * returns pointer to Date structure if successful,
 *         NULL if not (syntax error)
 */
Date *date_create(char *datestr);

/*
 * date_duplicate creates a duplicate of `d'
 * returns pointer to new Date structure if successful,
 *         NULL if not (memory allocation failure)
 */
Date *date_duplicate(Date *d);

/*
 * date_compare compares two dates, returning <0, 0, >0 if
 * date1<date2, date1==date2, date1>date2, respectively
 */
int date_compare(Date *date1, Date *date2);

/*
 * date_destroy returns any storage associated with `d' to the system
 */
void date_destroy(Date *d);

#endif /* _DATE_H_INCLUDED_ */
```

Answer (score 12):

You're defining `struct date` in date.c, datetest.c has no idea what it is. Declare it in date.h instead.  Currently it's an opaque type - anything that includes date.h can make a pointer to it, but can't access the members.

Comment: Move the `struct date {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};
` part into the header file.

Comment: In the task definition, it says that i am not supposed to edit the date.h file, just date.c. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Then you can either copy the struct definition into datetest.c, which is dangerous in case you change the definition in date.c. Or you could define accessor functions (`int getDay(Date *date)`) and either declare them in datetest.c or rely in implicit definition.

Comment: Can you create a new header? You could define accessor functions and put their forward declaration in a `datetest.h` file, then include that in `date.c`. Otherwise, your instructor is just encouraging bad practices.

Answer (score 3):

```
datetest.c:15:45: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct date'
  printf("Year: %d Month: %d Day: %d", d->year, d->month, d->day);
                                       ~^
./date.h:4:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct date'
typedef struct date Date;
```

When the compiler parses `date.h`, it detects that `date.h` doesnt have `struct date` but it uses `date`. So it throws that note `note: forward declaration of 'struct date'`

In `datetest.c` you have included `date.h` but not the actual definition which is in `date.c` and the compiler is not able to detect the type. Thats why it throws the error

```
error: incomplete definition of type 'struct date'
```

To fix this,

```
struct date {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};
```

Move this to `date.h` file.

Comment: In the task i'm given i'm only supposed to work only on date.c and datetest.c. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @martynas Nope :( You may have to define `date` and the `typedef` in all the `c` files which need it. Simple way is to move the definition of `date` to `date.h`

Comment: @martynas: You're trying to run the object file?

Comment: @martynas In nix you could run a `.out` file but not a `.o` file.

Comment: tried to run a wrong file :)
Everything seems to be working now. Unfortunately, i still need to get it to work without any alterations to the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Your program declares the `struct date` in the `.c` file which means you only have access to the things declared in the `.h` file.

The reason you can declare the `date` is because you make it a `pointer` and the compiler knows the size of all pointers. However, it knows nothing about the members of a `date` and, consequently, you are unable to call members like `d->year, d->month, d->day`, etc. Calling these members gives you your error.

One alternative is to make some interface functions which return the `year`, `month`, etc.

Since you are probably in a data structures class, and the header file is provided for you and have been instructed not to alter it. I would just call functions in the header file ONLY, and print things like `"passed"` when they work as expected and show the program did not segmentation fault, and leave it at that without needing to call `year`, `month`, etc.